# ASP.NET MVC 5: Datepicker in EditorTemplate error, cannot show multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have an `EditorTemplate` for `DateTime`, where I am using JQueryUI's `datepicker`. When I have **multiple dates** to be edited, only the first datepicker will show.

**Versions:**

```
<package id="jQuery" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

**../Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml:**

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() :
string.Empty), new
{
    @class = "form-control-static",
    @id = "datepick"
})
```

**../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml - script:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepick").datepicker({
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**The view where I'm trying to edit:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDateTime, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDateTime, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDateTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDateTime, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
```

As said, only the first one is working. I cannot find anything on google that helps me. Hope you can.

Comment: You need to give them unique ids, it's picking the first one. Try using a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have the same `id` for `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`.  Please see more about [select an item using an `id` or `class`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/)

> Since IDs are unique, this expression **always selects either zero or one elements** depending upon whether or not an element with the specified ID exists.

To solve this you have to use a `class`, because you can **select more than 1 element**.

Your code will change in something like this:

**../Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml:**

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() :
string.Empty), new
{
    @class = "form-control-static datepick",
})
```

**../Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml - script:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datepick").datepicker({
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```